# Remove p tags with PowerShell within specified Div class

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to clean up html code in alot of HTML files, basically what we want is remove all Paragraphs from within specific Div classes

I am trying to achieve this within powershell and got as far as finding the block of text to replace and remove the opening P and closing P tags within this text, but having troubles getting the updated text back in the HTML file

I have hundreds of files that contain one or more of these blocks

```html
<div class="SomeClass">
    <p various attributes>
    HTML formatted content
    </p>
</div>
```

What is the easiest way to update all .htm files such that the `<P>` tags within the "SomeClass" classes have been cleaned.

What I have now is

```bsh
$htmlCode = Get-Content $Testfile
$firstString = '<div class="SomeClass">'
$secondString = '</div>'
$pattern = "$firstString(.*?)$secondString"

$result = [regex]::Match($htmlCode, $pattern).Groups[1].Value

$cleanedHtml = $result -replace '<p[^>]+>',''
$cleanedHtml = $cleanedHtml -replace '</p>',''

$newHtmlCode = $htmlCode -replace $result, $cleaned
```

When I run this the `$newHtmlCode` contains the original code. I'm having troubles getting the old block replaced by the new block.

Comment: The text you want to match spans multiple lines, but your regex will never match b/c a) `.` does not match linefeed characters, and b) `Get-Content` doesn't read the file as a single string. Not to mention that you [shouldn't be using regular expression matches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171) for this in the first place. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30957667/1630171).

Comment: So out of interest, what would be the "best" way to remove the <p> tags within specifc div classes ? I have tried various solutions but nothing that works really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i achieved what i wanted with this piece of PowerShell code.
Im sure this could be done better, or shorter, but it worked for me.

```
$htmlCode = Get-Content $fileName -raw
$firstString = '<div class="SomeClass">'
$secondString = '</div>'
$pattern = "(?s)$firstString(.*?)$secondString"

$regex = [regex]($pattern)
$matches = $regex.Matches($htmlCode)

$updated = $false

foreach ($result in $matches)
{
    if ($result.Value -like '*<p*')
    {           
        [string]$original = $result.Value
        $cleaned = $original -replace '<p[^>]+>',''
        $cleaned = $cleaned -replace '<p>',''
        $cleaned = $cleaned -replace '</p>',''

        $htmlCode = $htmlCode.Replace($original, $cleaned)
        $updated = $true
    }
}

if ($updated)
{
    Set-Content -path $fileName -value $htmlCode -Encoding UTF8
    Write-Host "Updated $($fileName.FullName)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a similar problem, but took a different approach.  I've been using MSHTML to parse the document and manipulate the individual elements.

```
   $htmlCode = Get-Content $Testfile -raw    # -raw will read the file as a single string
   $HTML = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile" 
   $HTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($htmlCode)    # Write HTML content according to DOM Level2  
   $divNodes=$html.GetElementsByTagName("div") 
   foreach ($node in $divNodes) {
       if ($node.className="SomeClass")
       {
           $pNodes=$node.GetElementsByTagName("p") 
           foreach ($pNode in $pNodes) { 
               $pNode.removeNode($false) > $null # remove the p Tag, leaving the inside intact.  Get rid of the return value
           }
       }
   }
   $html.documentElement.innerHTML | Set-Content $TestFile # write the result back
```

I found it a bit easier to use than regular expression matching.

It looks like [HTMLAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) would make this even simpler, but I haven't tried that yet.