# How do I find out the type of parameter in a PowerShell script when working via COM?

Tags: windows, powershell, com

I am writing a script to work in the programs "Windows PowerShell" version 5.1 and "PowerShell" version 7 in the operating system "Windows 10".

I am creating an object via COM using a class [`HtmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument) from 'Windows Forms':

```
$dom = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
```

I want to use the method [`write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.write) of this class. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.write) says that it gets a [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string) type parameter. But passing a string of type `System.String` to the method `write` does not work:

```
$dom = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
[System.String] $str = "Text"
$dom.write($str)   # Error: type mismatch
```

I checked what type of parameter the method `write` requires:

```
$dom = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$dom | Get-Member write
```

And I got this result:

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{3050f55f-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b}

Name  MemberType Definition
----  ---------- ----------
write Method     void write (SAFEARRAY(Variant) psarray)
```

I read that [SAFEARRAY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-safearray) and [Variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant) are the structures in C++ used in [marshaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) when working with COM. Using these structures, you can transfer data in an array of any type. `SAFEARRAY` is an array that, in addition to data, stores information about itself. `Variant` is an array element, it can be of different types.

I found on 'Stack Overflow' the answers [jedigo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37380400/16458042), [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855426/16458042), [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655737/how-to-parse-html-table-with-powershell-core-7) from which it became clear to me that a byte array should be passed to the `write` method:

```
$dom = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
[byte[]] $str = 84, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 116, 0   # "Text" in encoding UTF-16LE
$dom.write($str)
```

or the same thing:

```
$dom = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$str = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("Text")   # UTF-16LE
$dom.write($str)
```

**My question**: how did people know that a byte array needs to be passed to the `write` method? This does not follow from the `SAFEARRAY(Variant)` information. Did they guess? Did they find the answer by going through different types? Is there any documentation in which this can be found?

I need to know the answer to this question because if in the future I work from 'PowerShell' via COM, then I may come across more similar cases and I will need to know the type of variable passed to the component.

Comment: You're making a confusion between IHtmlDocument2 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752574(v=vs.85) which is one of IE's entry COM object (write method: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752639(v=vs.85)), and HtmlDocument https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument which is a .NET Wrapper over the first one. You're using the first one. Both can be used (Powershell can program .NET), but the second one is easier.

Comment: Looks like you're right. But I do not know how to use the second way (.NET) in my case. Could you write an answer and demonstrate an analogue of my code in the second way (.NET)? I would accept such an answer as an answer to my question.

Comment: HtmlDocument from .NET can only be used in a WebBrowser context (it's a read-only member https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: I have a string with HTML code. I want to get an object from a string that is an analog of DOM. That is, the properties of the object must contain a tree of HTML elements. I was recommended to use the 'Html Agility Pack'. But I want to try this method first to figure out which one is better.

Comment: IHtmlDocument2+ and Winforms HtmlDocument are both based on mshtml ("Trident") the engine that came with IE. It's still supported but somewhat deprecated (won't be updated). Html Agility Pack is completely different (note: I'm the original author of it), its only .NET, has zero dependency, can read any html but doesn't run javascript. It should be much easier to use from PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL/DR: You have to know or guess with a little help from the documentation.

Technically passing a byte array of UTF-16 is not what the documentation says but the receiving function might handle multiple input formats.

If we look at the documentation for [`IHTMLDocument2::write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752639(v=vs.85)) we see it wants

> A SAFEARRAY of BSTR that specifies the text and HTML tags to write.

The example code on that page does:

```
...
SAFEARRAY *psaStrings = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1); // count is 1
VARIANT *param;
HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psaStrings, (LPVOID*)&param);
param->vt = VT_BSTR;
param->bstrVal = bstr; //SysAllocString
hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(psaStrings);
hr = document->write(psaStrings);
```

This is a SAFEARRAY with 1 entry in the array, a VARIANT. The variant is of type BSTR. BSTR is a counted array of WCHARs but can often be treated the same as a UTF-16LE string.

When Powershell asks COM, the part about BSTR has been lost. The array item type was probably not a part of the type library.

Some COM functions will only accept a single variant type while others might support multiple. Support for multiple might be hand-coded to a limited set or it might call `VariantChangeType` (unlikely).

Comment: I confused the 'HTMLDocument' (WinForms) class with 'IHTMLDocument2', otherwise I would have read the documentation for 'IHTMLDocument2' and figured it out. @Simon-Mourier correctly pointed this out to me in his comment. But your answer is also useful, so I marked it as an answer to my question.